# Creating private keys and CSR using openssl in java

Tags: java, openssl

I need to use Openssl in java code. e.g.

```
$ openssl genrsa -out RootCA.key 2048

$ openssl req -new -key RootCA.key -out RootCA.csr
```

When the above command will execute, I need to provide the input parameters like Org info etc..

```
$ openssl rsa -in RootCA.key.org -out RootCA.key
```

Is there any method to implement this?

Comment: It would be fine if there is anyway to achieve this in a batch script..

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with input parameters like CA, OU etc.

This you can provide in openssl.cnf file.

Following link may help you.

1. http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/config.html
2. http://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html

In case, you want to perform these operation in Java, you can call a C program from Java and write what you want to achieve in C program.